# Transpose DataFrame Pandas and add a new column

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to learn more about DataFrames with practical example I am working on. I got a table of two columns like that:

```
Grades    Count
Grade1    55
Grade2    42
Grade3    65
Grade4    70
```

How can this be transposed to be like that:

```
School    Grade1   Grade2   Grade3  Grade4
MySchool   55      42        65       70
```

as MySchool will be a variable of the type string

** I got the following in the csv file. How can I put header in the yellow cell?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need transpose and processing index with columns names convert column `Grades` to index, select column by `[[]]` to one column `Dataframe`, transpose by [`DataFrame.T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.T.html), `rename` index and set column name by [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
d = {'Count':'Myschool'}
df1 = df.set_index('Grades')[['Count']].T.rename(d).rename_axis('School', axis=1)
```

If only 2 column `DataFrame` is possible omit selecting column:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Grades').T.rename({'Count':'Myschool'}).rename_axis('School', axis=1)

print (df1)
School    Grade1  Grade2  Grade3  Grade4
Myschool      55      42      65      70
```

Another idea:

```
df1 = df.set_index('Grades')['Count'].to_frame('Myschool').T.rename_axis('School', axis=1)
```

Comment: Amazing. Thanks a lot my tutor. The table has Arabic characters so I modified like that `    df = df.set_index('الصف الدراسى')[['العــــــــدد']].T.rename({'العــــــــدد':myschool}).rename_axis('اسم المدرسة', axis=1)` but when exporting to csv I didn't get the title of the first header of the first column which should be `اسم المدرسة`

Comment: I tried the second idea and the result is OK except I didn't get the title of the first column

Comment: Thank you very much. I have posted a picture of the only problem which is the missing header in the yellow cell?

Comment: @YasserKhalil - One idea, how working if change `.rename_axis('School', axis=1)` to `.rename_axis('School', axis=0)` for set index name?

Comment: Amazing. Now it is completely solved. Thank you very much for your great support.