# Loop through schools append to dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, python-requests

I am working on scraping some data from schools and each school has three credentials (user1 - user2 - password)
I could create a function that enables me to scrape the name of each school
Here's the function

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = 'http://student.emis.gov.eg/new/index.aspx'

def get_data(user1, user2, password):
    with requests.session() as s:
        r = s.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
        viewstate = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATE').get('value')
        viewgenerator = soup.find('input', id='__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR').get('value')
        eventvalidation = soup.find('input', id='__EVENTVALIDATION').get('value')   
        data = {
            '__VIEWSTATE': viewstate,
            '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR': viewgenerator,
            '__EVENTVALIDATION': eventvalidation,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox1': user1,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox2': user2,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$TextBox3': password,
            'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$Button2': 'تسجيل دخول'
        }
        r_post = s.post(url, data=data)
        #print(r_post.content)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r_post.content, 'lxml')
        myschool = soup.select_one('#ctl00_Lblsch').text
        return myschool
```

and using Jupyter Notebook I used these lines to call the function like that

```
list = [('a','b','c'),('d','e','f')]
for item in list:
    user1 = item[0]
    user2 = item[1]
    password=item[2]
    print(get_data(user1, user2, password))
```

Till now everything is OK and perfect.

for each school I need to collect some data from another url and this is already done but only for one school

```
res_count = s.get('http://student.emis.gov.eg/new/staticts.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res_count.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df = df.drop([df.columns[0], df.columns[1]] ,  axis='columns')
df = df.set_index('الصف الدراسى')[['العــــــــدد']].T.rename({'العــــــــدد':myschool}).rename_axis('اسم المدرسة', axis=0)
df.to_csv('output.csv', encoding='utf-8-sig')
```

I was exporting the school data to csv file.
My question is how to store the data for each school so as to export the data of all the schools in one shot to one csv file ..??

The following link would show you the expected output
[Transpose DataFrame Pandas and add a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65072927/)
The output at the link was only for one school. I need to accumulate all the scraped data to only one csv file?

** I could return df for each school by adding the lines to the function like that

```
res_count = s.get('http://student.emis.gov.eg/new/staticts.aspx')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res_count.content, 'lxml')
table = soup.find_all('table', id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_GridView2')
df = pd.read_html(str(table))[0]
df = df.drop([df.columns[0], df.columns[1]] ,  axis='columns')
return df
```

But now I got each school data frame printed separately like that

[image]

** To make my request simpler: I have now multiple dataframes and I need to build or create only one dataframe so as to easily export all the data to one csv file?

Comment: @jezrael Thanks a lot fo helping me in the previous issue. Can you please have a look?

Comment: `pd.concat([df1,df2,df3], axis=0)` This stacks dataframes on top of each other.
`axis=1` will place them side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to merge DataFrames together in pandas you first make a list out of the Dataframes and then use the built-in concat function:

```py
list_of_dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
new_df = pd.concat(list_of_dfs)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question: how to convert the numbers to real number in the final dataframe as I noticed there are some spaces in the output?

Comment: When exporting the final dataframe I got all the results for both the two schools in one row ..? I expect to have the output for each school in one row?

Comment: Thank you very much. I have used your idea and it is perfect for me. Now it is solved.

Comment: @YasserKhalil I am glad to have helped. in regards to the spaces, perhaps it is saved as a string. If that is the case you would need to convert to remove the whitespace and convert to an int

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following function to combine arbitarily number of dataframes:

```
def combine_df(*dfs):
    """
    Concatenate data frames into one single data frame
    """
    if len(list(dfs)) > 1:
        final_df = pd.concat(list(dfs))
    else:
        final_df = list(dfs)[0]
    return final_df
```

you can use the following as below:

```
combine_dfs(df1, df2)
```

depending upon the number or arguments.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have defined an empty list like that `list_of_dfs = []` then in the loop I appended the dataframe like that `list_of_dfs.append(get_data(user1, user2, password))` . So in that case finally I have a list of dataframes, how can I apply the function you posted?